# How can pessimistic locking prevent a lost update?

Tags: sql, oracle, locking, isolation-level

I was reading Ask TOM
and he defines lost update as

> A lost update happens when:
>
> session 1: read out Tom's Employee record
>
> session 2: read out Tom's Employee record
>
> session 1: update Tom's employee record
>
> session 2: update Tom's employee record
>
> Session 2 will OVER WRITE session 1's changes without ever seeing them
> -- resulting in a lost update.
>
> Consider the web application that allows people to update their
> addresses and their phone numbers. the update statement used is
> always:
>
> update emp set address = :a, phone = :b where empno = :x;

In the optimistic concurency scenario you can use @version and avoid it.
However in a pessimistic locking scenarion like using SELECT FOR UPDATE or in another DBMS with pessimistic locking how can this particular example be prevented ?

If session 1 does

```
update emp set address = 'London', phone = 123 where empno = 10;
```

Session 2 blocks while doing

```
update emp set address = 'Brighton', phone = 456 where empno = 10;
```

Session 1 updates,commits.
Session 2 gets the fresh data but so what? It overwrites it anyway!

is that a lost update or not , and if yes how can it be revented under a pessimistic locking scenario?

Comment: if session1 and session2 are in a transaction nothing will be lost, as session 1 wiill executed and selects London and session 2 will update and it returns bristol. you can have an update column that tracks the last update, and if nothing should be lost add an audit table

Comment: "session 2: read" will pause/wait, since it's trying to read the same row as "session 1: read". The row will be released after it's updated and comitted by session 1. The commit will release the row and session 2 will be un-paused. Session 2 will see the new value, not the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing pessimistic locking, Session 2 would block doing the initial `SELECT` since both sessions were doing a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  Session 2 wouldn't be able to read the row until Session 1 committed its change.  At that point, the data that Session 2 would read would have Session 1's changes so there would be no lost update.

In real-world systems, it is exceedingly rare that you would want to have this sort of concurrency issues.  Or that, architecturally, you'd be able to.  Locking a row while a user edits it is pretty easy in a client-server application where each user gets their own dedicated connection to the database.  It is very difficult to do that in a web-based world where the end user communicates with a middle tier using a stateless protocol like HTTP and the middle tier maintains a pool of database connections that get used by a number of different users.

It appears that you may misunderstand what "lost update" means.  In this context, the fact that session 2 overwrites a change that session 1 made does not mean that there was a lost update.  A lost update would mean that session 2 overwrote the change session 1 made without ever seeing the change that session 1 made.  If you're doing a pessimistic lock, session 2 reads the change that session 1 made so session 1's change isn't a "lost update".

Comment: "At that point, the data that Session 2 would read would have Session 1's changes..".ok but it still overwrites the values address and phone,disregarding the change done by s1.I mean if now session1 does a select to retrieve the row again,it will get Brighton,not London

Comment: Isn't that considered lost update ?

Comment: Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @microwth - Added a comment at the end.  I think you misunderstand what a "lost update" refers to.

Comment: Thank you,the comment made it clear